# TargetInvocationException in SetValue(Reflection) inside of Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, reflection

I'm getting this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

When I insert extension method 'SetProperty' inside of ThreadStart:

```
Object temp = element;

PropertyInfo currentProperty = temp.GetType().GetProperty("FontSize");

object currentValue = currentProperty.GetValue(temp);

threads[i] = new Thread(
new ThreadStart(() => 
{ currentProperty.SetValue(temp, Convert.ChangeType(58, currentProperty.PropertyType), null); }));

threads[i].Start();
```

But when I use SetValue without Threading, everything works without any exceptions or errors.

```
PropertyInfo currentProperty = temp.GetType().GetProperty("FontSize");

object currentValue = currentProperty.GetValue(temp);

currentProperty.SetValue(temp, Convert.ChangeType(58, currentProperty.PropertyType), null);
```

Where could be a problem with using Thread?
I'm using C# 6, .NET 4.5.6.

Comment: I find this error: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.  Should I use another suliton? What about Dispatcher.Invoke? or how can I access the object of different thread, that owns it?

Answer (score 1):

This statement is true when using a thread: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
Assuming the calling thread is GUI, I'm not sure why you need an expensive thread to run your property code. 
To use dispatcher try:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    // Interact with code on a different thread.
});
```